# Affected Rows with Save/Delete/SaveOrUpdate in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, ado.net

I have an application using Nhibernate and I'm implementing a Repository Pattern. I would like to know if is there any way to take the number of rows affected and return it to the repository users, as we got on `ICommand.ExecuteNonQuery` in Ado.Net Providers. My code looks like this:

```
   public int Save(T entity) 
   {
       session.Save(entity);
       return ???
   }

   public int Delete(T entity) 
   {
       session.Delete(entity);
       return ???
   }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code NHibernate will throw an exception if the number of rows is not 1 (in your 2 cases above - well when you Flush the session anyway), so you can just return 1 from your Delete and Save methods - of course this makes returning the number of rows pointless.  Why do you want to return the number of rows?  If it's to check that NHibernate is doing what it's meant to do (ie. update 1 row or delete 1 row), I'd suggest trusting the tool to do it's job...